# Expression of central force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, symmetry, notation

Is $$\vec{F}(\vec{r})=F(r) \hat{r}$$ actually a formula or a general notation for central force? what is conveyed through this expression? I'm in the beginning stage of learning this concept so please don't think that the question is so silly.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a general notation of central force. It conveys two properties of $\vec{F}$:

1. $\vec{F}$ direction is radial.
2. $\vec{F}$ magnitude only depends on the radius from origin, not on $\theta$.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to mention that the force doesn't depend on the angle, only on the distance from the origin.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, it's always good to ask any type of question. I would say it is more of a general notation we use to express central forces.

The important thing you should note is the $\hat{r}$ unit vector, which means that every value of the force for a given point in space $r$ is always directed towards the center along the line that connects the object and the origin. In other words, as you move the vector of the force rotates so it is always directed towards/away the origin (depending on the sign).

These forces have several interesting applications to describe physical phenomena. An example of this, as you may know, is the gravitational interaction. In this case, the gravitational force that the Earth feels is always pointing towards the center of the solar system where the Sun is located (although to be precise, it is directed towards the center of mass between the Earth and the Sun).

Here's a nice animation to help you visualize how the force vector changes for a central force (centripetal force is just a type of central force): https://youtu.be/KvCezk9DJfk?t=26s